# Smallest $n$ with given number of solutions of $\frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{v} = \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

With $n,u,v$ being positive integers, let $T(n)$ be the number of ordered pair of positive integers $(u,v)$ such that

$$ \frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{v} = \frac{1}{n}$$

What is the smallest $N$ such that such that $N$ is a prime power and $T(N) = 13$?

What about a general $k$? How do we find the smallest $n$ such that $T(n) = k$?

> This problem is posed by [Sreejato B.](https://brilliant.org/mathematics-problem/sreejatos-ordered-pairs/)
>
> **Details:** A prime power is of the form $p^n$, where  is a prime number and  is a positive integer

Comment: This is (almost) Project Euler #108, just fyi.

Answer (score 3):

If I calculated correctly:

- T(1) = 1
- T(2) = 3
- T(3) = 3
- T(4) = 5
- T(5) = 3
- T(6) = 9
- T(7) = 3
- T(8) = 7
- T(9) = 5
- T(10) = 9
- T(11) = 3
- T(12) = 15

So, if you meant to ask for the smallest $n$ where $T(n) \ge 12$, that would be $n = 12$.  But $T(n)$ can never be *exactly* 12 because it's always odd.

tsillke gave one explanation.  Another way to see this is that, because of symmetry, solutions come in pairs: If $(u, v) = (a, b)$ is a solution, then so is $(u, v) = (b, a)$.  However, there's also always one solution with $u = v$, namely $(u, v) = (2n, 2n)$.  This is counted as a single solution instead of a pair, making the number of solutions odd.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is essentially equivalent to solving

$$\tau(n^2) = k$$

where $\tau(m)$ is the number of divisors of $m$

This we see by rewriting as

$$ (u-n)(v-n) = n^2$$

Notice that, this necessarily implies that $k$ must be odd (number of divisors of a perfect square is odd), and so $T(n) = 12$ has no solutions.

There might not be a simple solution for the general case.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing it as an answer so that it is more visible.

This is a [live Brilliant problem](https://brilliant.org/i/pnR22J/), and in fact proposed by me! I am requesting the other answerers to kindly delete their solutions till $5/8/2013$. For your information, there is a typo in the question. It should have been $f(n)= 13$

Comment: This seems rather like an attempt of disguising the problem than a typo.

Comment: @Tomas No, it is a typo, As tsillke pointed out, $T(n)$ must always be odd. For your information, I was the one who proposed this problem, and I have already solved it.

Comment: I am just saying, he also renamed the function from $f$ to $T$. So maybe he deliberately changed the value to $12$ (without knowing, that there is no solution) to disguise the problem. He received some answers, like the hint from tsillke, which he then could apply to the $13$ case.

Comment: That might be true. :) @Tomas